# Dummy data not loading In Spring Boot/React Selenium tests using PhantomJS

Tags: maven, selenium, reactjs, spring-boot, phantomjs

I have a spring boot project that uses React in the frontend. Maven uses npm to build the frontend and place a bundle.js in the target folder.

When spring is started and the website is viewed dummy data is loaded as a placeholder for when other things the application relies on aren't running (details are irrelevant).

I have set up PhantomJS to be dl'ed and used by Selenium for several acceptation tests I want to run. Setting all of this up has already taken me a while but it finally all works. I do however have a problem. The dummy data isn't loaded when viewing the page with PhantomJS.

[Screenshot manually running Spring Boot using Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zawon.png)

[Screenshot during test using PhantomJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6THD.png)

The configuration of PhantomJS in the test-class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RevCanApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class WebIT {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WebIT.class);
    private static String PHANTOMJS_BINARY;
    private static DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String path;
    private String screenshotpath = new ClassPathResource("screenshot.png").getPath();

@Autowired
private MeasurementsRepository measurementsRepository;

@LocalServerPort
int port;


@Before
public void init() throws InterruptedException {
    PHANTOMJS_BINARY = System.getProperty("phantomjs.binary");
    assertNotNull(PHANTOMJS_BINARY);
    assertTrue(new File(PHANTOMJS_BINARY).exists());
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
    capabilities.setCapability(
            PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
            PHANTOMJS_BINARY
    );
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX,"Y");
    capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20121026 Firefox/16.0");

    // Disable "web-security", enable all possible "ssl-protocols" and "ignore-ssl-errors" for PhantomJSDriver
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {
            "--web-security=false",
            "--ssl-protocol=any",
            "--ignore-ssl-errors=true",
            "--webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG"
    });
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    path = "http://localhost:" + port +"/";
}

@Test
public void testFilterOnId() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    driver.get(path);
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("idSelect")));
    List<WebElement> element = select.getOptions();
    log.info("There are " + element.size() + " elements in the list");
    screenshot();
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what the cause might be? Already spent several hours getting PhantomJS to render the react-page and now i'm stuck again...